# COM interface (MIDL): size_is for an optional [out] parameter

Tags: com, midl

In short, in the following definition:

```
HRESULT GetStuff([in] long count, 
                 [out, size_is(count)] long * a,
                 [out, size_is(count)] long * b);
```

which fills a and b with count elements, is it legal for the caller to set a and / or b to null?

I want to allow the caller to query only one set of results, so the method may be called with

```
long only_a_s[10];
itf->GetStuff(10, a, 0);
```

Do I need to modify the MIDL declaration? I'm unsertain how the pointer/pointer_default attributes play into this.

Notes: There's overhead in acquiring them separately, but so is acquiring values the caller doesn't need, so separate getters or always having to get both is sub-par. I know it does work for inproc / in-apartment calls, but would the MIDL-generated proxy/stub deal with that correctly?

Comment: I suggest you define three methods, one for `a`, one for `b` and one for `a` and `b`, so you don't have to hack your way thinking about null pointers.  Also, `HRESULT GetStuffA([in] long count, [out, size_is(, *pItems)] long **pA, [out] long *pItems);` allows you to request an amount, but actually return a different amount, typically equal to or less than the requested one, where the callee allocates the array with `CoTaskMemAlloc` and the caller frees it with `CoTaskMemFree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a null pointer as an argument (a.k.a. top-level pointer), as they're [`[ref]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367153(v=vs.85).aspx) by default.

But you may pass a null pointer, in or out, for non-top-level pointers.

The IDL method definition goes like this:

```
HRESULT GetStuffAB([in] long countA,
                   [in] long countB,
                   [out, size_is(, *pItemsA)] long **pA,
                   [out, size_is(, *pItemsB)] long **pB,
                   [out] long *pItemsA,
                   [out] long *pItemsB);
```

The C++ implementation:

```
HRESULT CMyClass::GetStuffAB(long countA,
                             long countB,
                             long **pA,
                             long **pB,
                             long *pItemsA,
                             long *pItemsB)
{
    // COM stubs will check this for you
    // However, you should (must?) manually check in same apartment calls
    if (!pA) return E_POINTER;
    if (!pB) return E_POINTER;
    if (!pItemsA) return E_POINTER;
    if (!pitemsB) return E_POINTER;

    *pA = nullptr;
    *pB = nullptr;
    *pItemsA = 0L;
    *pItemsB = 0L;

    if (countA < 0) return E_INVALIDARG;
    if (countB < 0) return E_INVALIDARG;

    // Get amount of As into *pItemsA if countA > 0
    // Get amount of Bs into *pItemsB if countB > 0

    if (*pItemsA < 0) return E_FAIL;
    if (*pItemsB < 0) return E_FAIL;

    if (*pItemsA > 0)
    {
        *pA = CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(long) * *pItemsA);
        if (!*pA) return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    }

    if (*pItemsB > 0)
    {
        *pB = CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(long) * *pItemsB);
        if (!*pB)
        {
            if (*pA)
            {
                // You should not assume the memory will be freed by the caller
                // in such drastic situations, so free and clear *pA here before returning
                CoTaskMemFree(*pA);
                *pA = nullptr;
            }

            return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        }
    }

    // Get As into *pA and Bs into *pB
    // Or just copy them if getting the amounts implied getting the items

    // You could just as well always return S_OK
    return (*pItemsA > 0 || *pItemsB > 0) ? S_OK : S_FALSE;
}
```

Not shown is whatever other code you must implement yourself to get the amount of `A`s and the amount of `B`s, and the `A`s and `B`s themselves.

If you must get the items to know the amounts, and you're not using RAII, you should free those resources manually before returning.

As an alternative to using `CoTaskMemAlloc` and `CoTaskMemFree`, you may want to use ATL's [`CComHeapPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80zw33a6.aspx), which will automatically free memory RAII-style, thus simplifying your code.  Just make sure you call [`Detach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5y0dxcc.aspx) into `*pA` and `*pB` before returning successfully.